# How to set a condition value for a variable in the constructor in Java?

Tags: java, constructor, conditional-statements

I'm trying to create a condition for the variable price to not be less than 0 in order to be valid using a constructor

This is my code

```
public void setPrice(){ 

if(price > 0){

    System.out.println("Valid value");}
else{

    System.out.println("Error");} }
```

Is there a different way to do it other than if statement?

Comment: What you are doing is mostly right, but that isn't a constructor. It's a setter.

Comment: Oh ok thank you for pointing that out I was a bit confused.

Comment: I want to make sure that the value of price cant be less than 0 in the constructor tho along with this setPrice method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bellow is some pseudo code of the constructor you have defined.

```
public nameOfClass(type param){

if(param > 0){
throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error parameter may not be lower than 0");
}


}
```

I believe this is how the constructor would work if you did not want the parameter to be less than zero

I also believe that and if statement is almost certainly the best way to go about this.

Comment: This is a bad solution.   If you do this and the parameter is incorrect, you print an error message, and then construct an object with an incorrect value anyway!

Comment: No? if the paramater passed in is greater than zero it is not set.

Comment: `public Food (double price){

        if(price < 0){
            System.out.println("not accepted"); } 
        
        else {
            this.price = price; }
}`

Comment: Can you suggest a way to improve this code then, please

Comment: @Eoghan_Mulcahy That's the problem! Not set means either `null` or default value.

Comment: @YousraM see Jay Andersons answer

Comment: @zyexal is this a good way to go about it? i see how it would be quite stupid to instantiate the class with invalid constructor values!

Comment: @YousraM see Stephen_C answer for detail. Eoghan_Mulcahys answer pointed on possibilities. You need to code yourself. So make a decision.

Comment: @Eoghan_Mulcahy - 1) If you don't do the check here, then the test still needs to be done somewhere else. 2) One reason for checking in the constructor (anyway!) is to picking up the kind of stupid (programmer) error you are talking about.  (Imagine there are lots of people working on this code ....)

Comment: `if (price > 0) {
   this.price=price;
} else {
   System.out.println("not accepted");
}`    I'm going to use this method but I need a way to stop someone from setting the value to zero or less when calling the method

Comment: @YousraM please don't!

Comment: And before someone mentions efficiency ( :-) ) ... yes, but in most cases the cost of an extra internal check is tiny compared to what else of going on.  That is, it most likely doesn't matter from a *practical* perspective.

Comment: Stephan's way is a bit outside of what the ms taught me so I can't really use it

Comment: But you will get an A

Comment: @YousraM - Really?  Aren't you >>allowed<< to learn something that your teacher hasn't taught you (yet)?

Comment: It's one of her stupid policies -,-! I used a new method in my first assignment that she didn't teach us and she gave me a zero saying that someone else solved my assignment even tho I actually watched tutorials and did it myself while fully understanding what I wrote!!

Answer (score 2):

If this is an internal check (e.g. it's a programming error at this point if it is not a positive price) you can use `assert`. Something like:

```
assert price > 0 : "Price must be positive."
```

If this is checking externally generated input an exception is a better option:

```
if (price <= 0) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("Price must be positive"); }
```

This still uses an `if`. Often these types of validation methods are put in utility methods. For instance guava has `Preconditions`:

```
Preconditions.checkArgument(price > 0, "Price must be positive");
```

Lastly there are validation frameworks where you setup your object and it checks that all of the conditions are satisfied (example: http://beanvalidation.org/)

Comment: Additionaly I would like to point on `com.google.common.primitives Unsigned` types and change `SomeSortOfException` to `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use stuff outside what we were taught so far. Still didn't take "assert" so I can't use it.

Comment: `if (price <= 0) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("Price must be positive"); }` is a good way but don't I need to set a value for price after making sure it's not <0 ? Like this.price = price;

Comment: See my answer for discussion of whether "assert" is an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to make sure that the value of price cant be less than 0 [...].
>
> Is there a different way to do it other than if statement?

No.

However, what you are doing is simply printing an error message *and continuing to use the invalid value*.  That does not achieve what you require.

Here's what I think you should do:

```
public void setPrice(int price){ 
    if (price <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("price not > 0");
    } 
    // set the price
}
```

If the `price` value is invalid, an exception is thrown and normal flow control is "interrupted".  You can catch and handle the exception in (for example) the method that calls this one.  Depending on where this is code is used the exception handler might ask the user for a correct value, reject the current request, skip a "record" in an input file and so on.  But the logic for doing that ... and even for reporting the problem is not the concern of the `setPrice` method.  This method is only responsible for checking and setting the price.

Alternatively, you can let the application terminate.  That is what would happen here.  `IllegalArgumentException` is an unchecked exception which means that the compiler won't insist that you do something about it.

You can do the same thing in a constructor.  But note that if a constructor terminates with an exception, the object that it was creating won't be completely initialized.  Usually it is thrown away.

---

@Jay Anderson suggests using `assert`.  This is a possible solution, but it is probably not appropriate here.  The problem is that checking of `assert` assertions can be turned off via a command line option.  (And indeed, assertion checking is "off" by default)

- You don't want people to be able turn off checks of user-supplied values.
- You don't want people to be able turn off checks of values supplied by other peoples' software.
- You don't want people to be able turn off checks of values supplied by other parts of your system.

Really, assertions are only appropriate if you are sure its is OK to run in production without the checks being performed ... at all.  My recommendation would be not to use them at all.  Instead use (separate) unit testing to pick up problems in your code.